# Can i create a feeder from extracting response from 1 request and pass the feeder values to next request in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

When i run my simulation file : it runs fine and response body looks like this

```
[
{
"id":1,
"region":US
},
{
"id":3,
"region:EUR
}
```

]

i am able to get a vector with values from id [1,3,....]
how can i convert this to iterator.continually(Mapvalues) of above feeder.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In this request, you can use check to save all ids to the session

```
.check(jsonPath("$[*].id").findAll.saveAs("ids")));
```

Step 2: In the next request, get this data from the session to do

```
.feed(data)
.exec(request1)    
.foreach("${ids}", "id") {
      exec(request2)
    }
```

Comment: i am able to retrieve the list from first request , but i want to pass that whole list in my second request instead of one by one.

Comment: Foe example :I get Vector(2,3,8,98,12,90) from first request , my second request is post which accepts some json as [{"id":2,"id":3,"id":8}]

Comment: Call this exec before you exec request2
```.exec(session => session.set("body", convertArrayToBodyString(session("ids"))))
```
Feel free to code method convertArrayToBodyString, I think you can do it easy in scala